# How can I integrate Appsee wireframe replays in my iOS app?

Tags: swift, appsee

I need to explore and integrate Appsee wireframe replay in my iOS app, and am unable to find any tutorial regarding the same.
Is there here any good tutorial available ?

Comment: In your opinion, what is missing from the official docs (https://www.appsee.com/docs/ios/native)?

Comment: I am not sure what Appsee means by "wireframe replay", is it the basic screen recording which is done by Appsee SDK or something else ? I already have Appsee screen recording integrated in my app, but since it creates issues with the Apple app review process hence am not using it anymore, I came across an article which suggested me to use Appsee with wireframe replay in order to successfully pass Apple app review process. And hence I wanted some details regarding it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Appsee's Wireframe replay is a solution which enables app developers to visualize in-app behavior without recording the app’s screen (see here: https://blog.appsee.com/appsee-product-update-new-ios-sdk-release/)

Starting iOS SDK v2.5.1, each new app integration is automatically configured to use Wireframe Replay (as opposed to screen recording), therefore downloading the [latest SDK](https://www.appsee.com/downloads/get) and following the [integration guide](https://www.appsee.com/docs/ios/native) should be enough.